# Magento2 API must use fully qualified namespaces?

Tags: magento2, api, interface

In Magento2.1, I see almost all API use the **fully qualified namespaces** in the function **param** and **PHPDoc**, instead of using **importing and aliases**, like `PageRepositoryInterface` and `BlockRepositoryInterface` in the `vendor\magento\module-cms\Api` directory.

I forgot where I saw it, but I remember someone said Magento2 API must use fully qualified namespaces, is that true? If it is true, what is the **reason**?

### For Example

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Cms\Api;

interface PageRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Save page.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface $page
     * @return \Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function save(\Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface $page);
}
```

Can it rewrite to below?

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Cms\Api;

use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface;

interface PageRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Save page.
     *
     * @param PageInterface $page
     * @return PageInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function save(PageInterface $page);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 is trying to switch to use **importing and aliases**, but you may understand there is no out-of-the-box tool to convert the whole Magento 2 code like that...

And it's not true that Magento 2 **must use** fully qualified namespaces.

For more information: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/872

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link. I remember someone said the api can not use simplified
 namespace in the **PHPDoc**, otherwise the web api will produce some error, because **PHPDoc** doesn't recognize it.  Is it OK to use simplified
 namespace in the  **PHPDoc**?  You could see the example I given in the question.

Comment: Hi, I find a official DevDocs about the fully qualified namespaces in PHPDoc, you could have a look. Not sure it is right. [Another answer about the doc block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/201362/44237)

Answer (score 4):

After a research, finally find the source in my memory, it is in official develop guide [Configure services as web APIs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html).

> For SOAP and REST to work correctly, the following rules **must** be followed by the **service interface’s doc block**:
>
> Note that even if the class `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` is in the same namespace (or a sub-namespace) of the current class or a use statement has exists at the top of the class, the **fully qualified namespace must be used** or **the web API throws an exception**.

We seems could use simplified namespace in the **function param** as the answer of @Toan, but we **must** use fully qualified namespace in **service interface’s doc block** as the official develop guide said, but it doesn't say the **reason**, so any more
explanation answer is welcome.

Comment: The reason is in code generation and smart resolving for input- and return-values for the API. For example, a GET to `/V1/products` returns a JSON object. The `webapi.xml` maps this to `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getList`, and it's API makes sure it will return a `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface`. The `Magento_Webapi` has some complexity (too much to explain here), but basically it converts the data model according to getters in it's interface to a JSON response. If you create proper Service Contracts your API endpoints work out of the box!